# A word meaning both risky and pragmatic

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an academic research proposal, which has to satisfy two things: a degree of risk, and a degree of feasibility. This is slightly contradictory though, so I'm wondering what is the best word to use.

I would like to say something similar to:

"With this opportunity, I aim to investigate these ideas...".

This gives a sense of open-endedness and risk, but I also want to say something that suggests there will be tangible outputs, such as:

"With this opportunity, I aim to implement these ideas...".

However, this sounds like there is not risk or exploratory element to the work.

What would be a great word to use in this case?

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Single word requests as yours are required to provide an example sentence about the way the word will be used.

Comment: I don't know of such a word. Why not simply use _"I aim to implement these **risky pragmatic** ideas"_?

Comment: Or just combine them slightly differently again. "...I aim to investigate the implementation of these ideas,,," You will investigate, and that investigation may well end up with the ideas implemented.

Comment: "With this opportunity, I aim to _explore the practicality_ of these ideas..."? "With this opportunity, I aim to _test_ these ideas..."?

Answer (score 2):

***[validate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/validate)*** - MW:

> Definition of **validate**
>   (*validated*; *validating*)
>   *transitive verb*
>
> 2 a :  to support or corroborate on a sound or authoritative basis :
>   experiments designed to **validate** the hypothesis

This word acknowledges that the ideas are not *proven* yet (hence, the risk element) but are *promising* enough to be tried out.

> "With this opportunity, I aim to ***validate*** these ideas...".

Answer (score 0):

"With this opportunity, I aim to test these ideas..."

> **test**
>
> to do something in order to discover if something is safe, works correctly, etc., or if something is present

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/test

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is

**cutting-edge**

"at the latest or most advanced stage of development; innovative or pioneering:
*cutting-edge technology*" (which was google's first suggestion)